# Scoping bug using locals() and an import within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I have code that looks something like this:

```
def outer(*args):
    import os

    def inner():
        def fget(self):
            print(os)

        def fset(self, arg):
            print(os)

        return locals()

    return property(**inner())

outer()
```

But when ran, I get:

> TypeError: 'os' is an invalid keyword argument for property()

Which means that `os` is within the local scope of `inner`.  *Why is that?*

If I replace `import os` with a simple variable declaration, the variable isn't within the scope of `inner`, so no error is thrown:

```
def outer(*args):

    os = 'foo'

    def inner():
        def fget(self):
            print(os)

        def fset(self, arg):
            print(os)

        return locals()

    return property(**inner())

outer()
```

Or, if I move `import os` to the global scope of the module, no error is thrown:

```
import os

def outer(*args):

    def inner():
        def fget(self):
            print(os)

        def fset(self, arg):
            print(os)

        return locals()

    return property(**inner())

outer()
```

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `import`. When you changed the import to `os = 'foo'`, you also stopped actually using `os` inside `inner`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I don't understand.  I never used `os` within the local scope of `inner` to begin with?  The `import os` is in the local scope of `outer`.

Comment: When posting simplified code, please make sure your simplified code still runs and reproduces the behavior your question is about. None of your snippets raise an error, because `print('do something with os')` doesn't actually do something with `os`.

Comment: "I never used `os` within the local scope of `inner` to begin with" - are you saying that `print('do something with os')` is not actually a replacement for code that did something with `os`?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica My bad, you are correct.  If I don't use `os` within `fget` or `fset`, the error doesn't trigger.  That being said, the local scope of `fget` **isn't** the local scope of of `inner`.